# java 8u60 webview load local files

Tags: java, html, webview, local

i have a problem with new release of java 8u60.
I have an application with webView component and html pages with images,css and javascript files.
In 8u51 i loaded html page via:

```
     webView = new WebView();
webView.getEngine().load(Theory.class.getResource("tree.html").toExternalForm());
```

and in my page I loaded css,images,javascripts etc. via simple html commands like:

```
<a href="AVLRotation.html">Rotation</a>
 <img src="images/AVLTable1.png" alt="Graph"  class="center-block"  />
```

AVLRotation.html is in same folder like my page, AVLTable1.png is in folder images near the my page.

I loaded this files from local resource in my JAR file. In 8u51 everything worked great. In 8u60 html page loads but local resources like images, javascript, css dont. `a href` command with name of pages in the same directory dont work either and i cant find any help or solution.

Comment: Please edit your question (using the "edit" link under the shaded keyword rectangles beneath your question) to include the code where you call WebEngine.load.  The actual URL you are loading may be a factor.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior.  It works in 1.8.0_51 but not in 1.8.0_60.  Definitely a bug.  I cannot find an entry in the Java Bug Database for it, but it may be related to http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8123764 .

Comment: I have the same problem, since 8u60 javascript is not loaded anymore

Comment: I ended up with the solution given in the comment to the answer in this question - insert a template string and replace with the content of the JavaScript or css file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429069/loading-local-javascript-file-in-webview-in-java-8u60