# Loading local JavaScript file in WebView in Java 8u60

Tags: java, javafx-webengine

Until Java 8u51, the following worked fine:

- Have an HTML file containing `<script src="javascript.js"></script>`
- Load this HTML file into a WebView
- Call a function contained in `javascript.js` using `webView.getEngine().executeScript()`

After switching to 8u60 however, it no longer works:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So the file `javascript.js` is no longer loaded. *It works* when started from an IDE, where JavaScript file just lies on the file system. However, *it no longer works* when the application is packaged and therefore `javascript.js` is inside a JAR file.

Any idea what has changed and how this can be fixed?

Comment: It's not JDK/jre fault, it doesn't find your js file(you may locate it beside the jar and a have a try), I believe you set the target js file path wrong

Comment: Why did it work before but not anymore then?

Comment: Becasue IDE does not generate a jar file then run it, and you are doing that way, you need to specify the javascript file it's a embed jar resource

Comment: By "it *no longer works* when the application is packaged" I meant it works with u51 but doesn't with u60 - both run from JAR files.

Comment: Most likely the problem with the javascript code inside the file. Is it possible for you to post the javascript file here?

Comment: It's not the content. Specifying the file as an URL instead of a relative path works.

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 8u60, local javascript files referenced in html files are not executed anymore in the WebView. When running the program with an older version, it still works.
I found no information that this change in behaviour was intended by Oracle.

As a workaround you can either place the javascript code directly into the HTML file, or load in java the contents of the javascript file into a String and execute it with `webView.getEngine().executeScript()`

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any information either. My workaround is having a placeholder {javascript-file}, reading the HTML into a string and then then string-replace the placeholder with `getResource("javascript.js").toURI()` or so. Ugly but at least it works.

Comment: Actually, this is the solution I also ended up using. It's not pretty, but it works for now.

Comment: Thanks, had same situtaion, a fix is coming in 8u72: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136466